# how to change time in the same line

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    time_t ltime;
    time( &ltime );
    tm *    pTm = localtime(&ltime);
    while(true)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            if(i==999)
            {
                printf("Program time is: %02d:%02d:%02d \r", pTm->tm_hour, pTm->tm_min, pTm->tm_sec);
                i=0;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

but it's not looping !!?

Comment: `for(int i=0:i=1000;i++)` Huh?

Comment: There are typos in the program. If your condition is `i==1000`, for loop never executes and the while loop runs infinitely.

Comment: That and what's the colon in the `for`?

Comment: guys i wrote the code here so i didnt notice that i made typo lol

Comment: Just a comment: You'll want to add a sleep condition something like `usleep(10000)` in linux or `Sleep(10)` in Windows at the bottom of the `while()` loop or this will eat up your CPU.

Comment: As written, your `while (true)` is redundant. If `i` = 999, you reset it to 0. Therefore your condition in your `for` loop is never false, and thus is in itself also in infinite loop, same as the `while` was apparently supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to refresh `pTm` each iteration if you want the values to change.

```
while(true)
{
    // get pTm again here.
    sprintf(buf, "Program time is: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", pTm->tm_hour, pTm->tm_min, pTm->tm_sec);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\r` at the end of the `printf()` format string.

**Edit:** And as aaz has mentioned, you should `fflush(stdout)`, since it is line buffered by default.

Comment: Don't forget to `fflush(stdout)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
  while(true) {
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *t = localtime(&now);
    printf("Program time is: %02d:%02d:%02d \r", t->tm_hour, t->tm_min, t->tm_sec);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```